# Insert objects into object Mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I'm trying to insert objects into an object(not an array). How do I go about and do that?

Here is an example of the structure of the data I'm trying to achieve.

```
users:{
 '0': {
    name: 'Tom',
    age: '19',
    car: 'Mazda 3',
  },
 '1': {
    name: 'Ryan',
    age: '27',
    car: 'BMW',
  },
 '2': {
    name: 'Jake',
    age: '22',
    car: 'Audi',
  }
}
```

`users` is a field in a document that contains a collection of users. I want to add new users to the `users` field and when I add them the keys inside the users should increment accordingly.

so the newly added object should be:

```
'3': {
        name: 'Sam',
        age: '24',
        car: 'Honda',
      }
```

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
let newUser = {
            name: 'Sam',
            age: '24',
            car: 'Honda',
          };

db.collection('Group').findOneAndUpdate({
   '_id': new ObjectId(groupId),
}, {
  '$set': {
     'users.$': newUser,
   },
}, {
   returnOriginal: false,
}
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up `$update` - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: Let me update the question quickly. `users` is a field in a document. I want to add new user objects to the `users` field. Also, I want the keys in the `users`  to increment when I add a new user object.

Comment: @thishandp7 I think you should change your Model.
users should not be an object, it should be an array then your problem will be solved . otherwise you will  have to get the length of the users object first and then create an new object with `{length+1:{your user object}}` and then you have to push this created object into your users objects.

Comment: @Yogesh.Kathayat because why do simple when you can do complicated :)

Comment: @Yogesh.Kathayat That's how i'm creating the object to be inserted into the document. Also, I'm using a $set operator. The $set operator replaces the existing data with the new one. It's not adding a new one like $push does for arrays. And yes I agree on changing the model to use an array. But, unfortunately, I don't have the control over the DB. And the DB is currently used by some other applications as well. So changing the model is not an option for me.

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, it is a complicated way to do it. But, I'm stuck since changing it into an array would break other applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourModel.create(req.body,function(err,result){
   console.log(result);
});

suppose your req.body will 

 {name: 'Sam',age: '24',car: 'Honda' };
```

2nd way :

```
 user.collection.create(req.body,function(err,result){
   console.log(result);
});

suppose your req.body will 

 {name: 'Sam',age: '24',car: 'Honda' };
```